# DNA.Land vs AncestryDNA

Tags: dna, ancestry.com, ethnicity-dna, dna.land

I received results back from DNA.Land.

**Northwest European**
*Includes*: Scottish Argyll_Bute_GBR and British in England; Icelandic in Iceland; Norwegian in Norway and Orcadian in Orkney Islands
*Does not include*: Saharawi in (Morocco) Western Sahara; Piapoco in Colombia; Estonian in Estonia; Basque/French and French in (South and 1 other site) France; Basque/Spanish and Iberian Population in Spain; Finnish in Finland and Gambian in Western Gambia

**North Slavic**
*Includes*: Belarusian in Belarus; Estonian in Estonia; Lithuanian in Lithuania; Mordovian and Russian in Russia and Ukrainian in (East) Ukraine
*Does not include*: Altaian, Kalmyk, Nganasan and Adygei in (Caucasus and 3 other sites) Russia; Turkmen in Uzbekistan; Albanian in Albania; Bulgarian in Bulgaria; Italian/Bergamo in (Bergamo) Italy; Norwegian in Norway; Ashkenazi Jew in Poland; Turkish in (Istanbul) Turkey; Finnish in Finland and Ashkenazi Jew from East Europe especially Lithuania (expat in Baltimore MD)

**South/Central European**
*Includes*: Italian/Bergamo, Italian/Tuscan and Toscani in (Bergamo, Tuscany and 1 other site) Italy
*Does not include*: Albanian in Albania; Basque/French in France; Italian/EastSicilian, Italian/WestSicilian and Sardinian in (Sardinia and 2 other sites) Italy and Lithuanian in Lithuania

**Balkan**
*Includes*: Albanian in Albania; Bulgarian in Bulgaria and Greek in (2 sites) Greece
*Does not include*: Egyptian in (2 sites) Egypt; Belarusian in Belarus; Italian/EastSicilian, Italian/Bergamo and Toscani in (Bergamo and 2 other sites) Italy; Lithuanian in Lithuania; Ashkenazi Jew in Poland; Turkish in (Aydin, Balikesir and Istanbul) Turkey; Ukrainian in (East) Ukraine and Ashkenazi Jew from East Europe especially Lithuania (expat in Baltimore MD)

**AncestryDNA**:

52 percent czech republic
england wales northwestern europe 23 percent (central southern england)
18 percent ireland/scotland
3 percent swedish
4 percent norway

What accounts for the difference?

Does DNA.Land trace things farther back as I'm allegedly told?

Answer (score 3):

> Does DNA.Land trace things farther back as I'm allegedly told?

No. Different labs use different algorithms (including Machine Learning) to get the ethnical compound. Also they have different basic populations and reference values. So it is not big surprise that they will give you different results.
If you would like to get more results and have a total mess in your head, I recommend you to upload your RAW DNA results to [GEDMATCH](https://www.gedmatch.com/login1.php) site. It is free and there are dozens of different ethnocalculators. I hope you will be interested and get more precise results about your ethno mix up.
Also please use all these results with the grain of salt, because it is really very new part of science and every model has it's own probability and limits.

P.S. Another thing I know is that DNA.Land is going to shut down or full restart of project.